# What's the difference between screen size and desktop size?

Tags: graphics, directx

I frequently see screen size and desktop size in graphics programming forum or some documents, Isn't screen size equal to desktop size? take the following as an example, what's the differences?

> For windowed mode, the size of the destination surface should be the
>   size of the desktop. For full-screen mode, the size of the destination
>   surface should be the screen size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the Desktop Size does NOT always fill the screen. Change your resolution to maybe 800x600 or (if possible) 640x480, and you will see that on many screens, it will only occupy a small area on the display. Screen size = the full amount your screen can show. Desktop size is that box that I just described. MOST cases, they are the same - but not always.

It also, depending on the context, may be describing what fits inside the current window, minus the title bar, tool bars, task bar, etc.

Comment: Note that there are cases in which a desktop is larger than the available screen resolution. In this case, you can usually pan across the desktop.

Comment: @ysap That would be assuming they are working on a Windows machine. I know Linux, as far as I know, hasn't got that standard yet, and for Mac OSX, I don't think they do either. But yes, I do see it says DirectX (meaning Windows) - I'm just mentioning that fact.

Comment: honestly, I was not referring to Windows or Direct X in particular. Rather, just wanted to clarify that the distinction between screen and desktop resolution go both ways. What I had in mind actually was LogMeIn and VNC viewer on my lower res laptop when connected to a high res computer. You can either "zoom out" to see the whole shrinked desktop, or pan in 1:1 zoom.

Comment: @ysap Sorry, I just threw that info out there for educational purposes - I can see you're no amateur by your rating. Personally, I think it SHOULD be standard in all OS's anyway - it can be very useful.